# Updating a EJS file after a different option value is selected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have the following files:

my EJS page with `<select>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

     <%- include('../views/partials/header.ejs') %>

  <body>
    <h1 style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">AidaLinux</h1>

    <%- include('../views/partials/nav.ejs') %>
    
<div class="table-responsive" style="padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;" >
  <h2><%= name.printername %> jobs List</h2>
<!-- select in question -->
<!-- this prints all my available printers  -->
  <select class="form-select" onchange="onChange();">
    <% for ( var i = 0; i<name.length; i++ ) { %>
        <option value="<%= name[i] %>"> <%= name[i] %> </option>
        <% } %>

    </select>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-borderless">
      <thead>
        <tr class='table-dark'>
          <th scope="col">Job Rank</th>
          <th scope="col">Job Commissioner</th>
          <th scope="col">Job ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Job File Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Job Size</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <% for(var i=0; i<command.length; i++){ %>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><%= command[i].rank %></th>
            <th scope="row"><%= command[i].owner %></th>
            <th scope="row"><%= command[i].identifier %></th>
            <th scope="row"><%= command[i].files %></th>
            <th scope="row"><%= command[i].totalSize %></th>
          </tr>
        <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

    <div class="table-responsive" style="padding: 20px 20px 50px 20px;" >
    <h2>All Printer Jobs List</h2>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-borderless">
      <thead>
        <tr class='table-dark'>
          <th scope="col">Printer name</th>
          <th scope="col">Job Commissioner</th>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% for(var i=0; i<job.length; i++){ %>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><%= job[i].printername %></th>
            <th scope="row"><%= job[i].owner %></th>
            <th scope="row"><%= job[i].date %></th>
          </tr>
        <% } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <%- include('../views/partials/footer.ejs') %>
<!-- test function to test the onchange -->
  <script>function onChange(){
    console.log("ciao");
  }</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my function sent with express, it's only a part of the whole file `cupsApis.js`, where all my functions are stored, like this i only have to do one request in `app.js` and i have them all available there, but that's the one i'm interested in

```js
lpq = function (name) {
  let self = this;
  self = utils.list()[6];
  let args = ["-P", self];
  let lpq = spawnSync("lpq", args, { encoding: "utf-8" });
  let stdoutSpawnSync = utils.parseStdout(lpq.stdout);
  stdoutSpawnSync.shift();
  stdoutSpawnSync.shift();

  let InfoJob = stdoutSpawnSync.map(function (line) {
    line = line.split(/ +/);
    return {
      rank: line[0] === "active" ? line[0] : parseInt(line[0].slice(0, -2)),
      owner: line[1],
      identifier: parseInt(line[2]),
      files: line[3],
      totalSize: parseInt(line[4]),
    };
  });
  return InfoJob;
};
```

my express file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cups = require("./api/cupsApis.js")

app.listen(3000);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/home");
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/lpq", (req, res) => {
  const name = cups.lpstat()
  const command = cups.lpq();
  const job = cups.lpstatJobs();
  res.render("lpqView", {
    command,
    job,
    name,
  });
});

app.get("/classes", (req, res) => {
  res.render("classes");
});

app.get("/lpstat", (req, res) => {
  const command = cups.lpstat();
  res.render("lpstatView", {
    command,
  });
});

app.get("/lp", (req, res) => {
  const command = lp("/home/finsoft/ProgettoStampanti/file/file.txt");
  console.log("command", command);
  res.render("lpView", {
    command,
  });
});

app.get("/lpadmin", (req, res) => {
  const command = cups.lpadmin("PrinterProva2", "HP Printer", "FINSOFT");
  res.render("lpadminView", {
    command,
  });
});
```

What i'm trying to achieve is a  'refresh' of this EJS page when i click on a different `<option>` of the `<select>`, and when it happens i will change the values inside the first table, so i will see the current jobs for the selected printer.

I tried to find something online and a `AJAX` call and a `fetch` where the first results, i tried learning something about those topics with some example, but failed.

can someone explain what should i do? are those the only to methods? am i doomed to study them?

Answer (score 0):

The question almost looks like "implement a feature for me", but if the gist was: is it possible to make a dynamic form without using AJAX, then the answer is yes. You can define a `<form>` and submit it programmatically with JS in the `onChange()` function (instead of outputting "ciao").

AJAX would make the user experience much better though, since the page would not reload. It just looks weird if the user is on the form and suddenly page starts loading and then turns to be the same page with just a few fields changes. With AJAX you can display a nice in-progress animation (a spinner) and simply update the current page based on the server response. It slightly more work though.

So answering to your second question: you are doomed to study if you wish to be a good developer. And not only regarding AJAX but you'll have to study through your entire career.